# 3D view with a touchscreen in Windows 10 (Surface pro 4), how to zoom, rotate, pan

Tags: 3d-view

I have a MacBook pro, and I can use the touchpad for:

- pinch with 2 fingers -> zoom in and out
- move two fingers up, down, left or right -> rotate around the object
- Shift + two fingers movements -> pan left right up down.

Now I purchased a surface pro 4, and blender windows version seems to not have the same default way to move the camera. The touch screen acts like a simple mousewheel but only do pan view when pinching screen, it can't zoom or rotate.

Is there a way to configure Blender to do so? but I mean, with the internal code, same as the Mac Blender version, not configuring windows gestures or key bindings on blender preferences.

Comment: Why do you have to change the internal code? That doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: I don't think touchscreen input is currently well supported, though I've heard the situation may improve for the 2.8 series

Comment: @pycoder nono, I have wrongly expressed my self, I don't mean to modify the internal code, I meant using the internal code, without doing any modification to the code using addons or scripts. I say so, because, if it's there in Mac Blender version, It has to be somewhere in the windows version aswell I suppose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the surfacepro needs it's key board for functionality:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> pen/touch to orbit
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> pen/touch to translate
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> pen/touch to zoom

Note: I have *Emulate 3 Button* mouse enabled.

Touch functionality is something that will be worked on in the [Google Summer of Code][1].

Scroll down to Trackpads, smooth scrolling, and multitouch support

"Benefits: Blender should get cross-platform support for modern input devices. Linux and Windows (Surface Pro) are falling behind."

"[1]: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/GoogleSummerOfCode/2017/Ideas

Comment: ok thanks a lot Patdog for all information.