# how to setup blender for Surface Pro 4

Tags: interface

Using blender on Surface Pro 4. 
I've set the virtual pixel mode to "double" and it's great for the display UI. But I can't manipulate anything with the rotate tool using either the pen or a mouse.

I've tried playing with the manipulator size and handle size, but that doesn't help.

I also can't navigate/move the view using the pen.

Anyone have any setup suggestions to get me going?

Comment: You should have Emulate 3 Button mouse enabled - you can find that under Input in the Preferences. This might be helpful https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75288/3d-view-with-a-touchscreen-in-windows-10-surface-pro-4-how-to-zoom-rotate-p/75389#75389

Comment: Thanks @Patdog, Emulate 3 Button mouse let me use the pen.

Answer (score 1):

The *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* setting let me use the pen to interact with objects and the scene.

The problem I was having with the rotate manipulator turned out to be a separate issue, and was fixed by changing the *selection* mode under User Preferences>System from *automatic* to *OpenGL Occlusion Queries*.